# Javascript how to add active class to clicked element and hide all others

Tags: javascript

I have a list-item-menu, where when I click on one of them it gets an active class, while I want all other list-items to get hidden but I'm not sure how to do that.

Here is my script so far:

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item');

items.forEach((item) => {
   item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      item.classList.toggle('active')

      // HIDE ALL OTHER "item"-elements
  })
});
```

can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can implement that function like this.

```
 const items = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item');

items .forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {   
   items .forEach(a=>{
      a.classList.remove("active");
      a.style.display = 'none'; 
    });
     item.classList.add("active");
     item.style.display = 'block'; 
    
  });  
});
```

Comment: There's no reason to change `display`. If the OP wants to hide elements that don't have the `active` class, that's what CSS is for. :-)

Comment: Well I thought @ST80 want to show all element at first and hide all elements when click  item except an that clicked element.

Comment: @EtsukoSusui you are absolutely right!! :-)

Comment: @EtsukoSusui - Right! Which, again, is what CSS is for. `.menu-item { display: none; }` and `.menu-item.active { display: block; }`. :-)

Comment: Well then all elements will not display at first time.

Comment: If all elements does not display, how can we click it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function for compare index and toggle class. 
I used colors for the example:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item');

items.forEach((item, idx) => {  
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {   
    ToggleActive(item,idx);
  });
});

function ToggleActive(el,index) {
  el.classList.toggle('active');
  items.forEach((item,idx) => {
    if(idx !== index){
      item.classList.remove("active");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.active{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='menu-item'>Menu 1</div>
<div class='menu-item'>Menu 2</div>
<div class='menu-item'>Menu 3</div>
<div class='menu-item'>Menu 4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item");
      items.forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
          item.classList.toggle("active");
          let itemsArray = [...items];
          let array = itemsArray.filter((item) => item !== e.target);
          array.forEach((elem) => {
            //   to toggle hidden
            elem.hidden = !elem.hidden;
          });
        });
      });
```

```html
<button class="menu-item">1</button>
<button class="menu-item">2</button>
<button class="menu-item">3</button>
<button class="menu-item">4</button>
<button class="menu-item">5</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to listen for event on the parent element (here the `ul`) and then you can use `closest()` to find the element that you need to be active.

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');

ul.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let li = e.target.closest('li');
  if (li) {
    ul.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(elm => elm.classList.remove('active'));
    li.classList.add('active');
  }
});
```

```css
li.active a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="1">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="2">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="3">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="4">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `document.getElementsByClassName` to do that.

An example of that would look like so;

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.menu-item')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
```