# foreach in javascript menutoggle should be active in the icon I clicked in only

Tags: javascript, django

I hope you are doing well, I am using django, problem is I have a list of items that contains a menuToggle my code is like this

```
<!--here is code .... -->
<div class="container">
            {% ifequal request.user.username obj.author.user.username %}
                <div class="action1">
                    <div class="icon" onclick="menuToggle1();">
                        <img src="{% static 'images/ore.svg'%}" class="svg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="menupost" id="menupost">
                        <ul>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:10px;"></i><a href="{% url ''%}">Update</a></li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:10px;"></i><a href="{% url ''%}">Delete</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h2 id="title" class="title">{{obj.title}}</h2>
<!--and so on...-->
</div>
```

```
<script>
    function menuToggle1(){
        
        document.querySelectorAll('.menupost').forEach(function(element) {
            element.classList.toggle('active');
        });
    };  
</script>
```

so when I click on one of them , I see all the menu of all items.
so I don't want to see all menutoggle when I click on just one of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript how to add active class to clicked element and hide all others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67599360/javascript-how-to-add-active-class-to-clicked-element-and-hide-all-others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently just toggling the active class on all `.menupost` elements. Instead you need to remove the active class from all of them, and then only add it to the sibling of the clicked element.

This is a little trickier, but one way to do it is to check if the `event.target` is inside the same parent element as the currently iterated `.menupost` element. Here using [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to retrieve the closest common ancestor. You also need to pass the event to the callback in your `onclick` declaration.

```js
function menuToggle1(event) {
  const active_ancestor = event.target.closest('.action1');
  
  document.querySelectorAll('.menupost').forEach(function (element) {
    element.classList.remove('active');

    if (active_ancestor === element.closest('.action1')) {
      element.classList.add('active');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="action1">
    <div class="icon" onclick="menuToggle1(event);">
      <img src="{% static 'images/ore.svg'%}" class="svg">
    </div>
    <div class="menupost" id="menupost">
      <ul>
        <li><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:10px;"></i><a href="{% url ''%}">Update</a>
        </li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:10px;"></i><a href="{% url ''%}">Delete</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2 id="title" class="title">{{obj.title}}</h2>
</div>
<div class="container">  <div class="action1">      <div class="icon" onclick="menuToggle1(event);">          <img src="{% static 'images/ore.svg'%}" class="svg">      </div>      <div class="menupost" id="menupost">          <ul>              <li><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:10px;"></i><a href="{% url ''%}">Update</a></li>              <li><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:10px;"></i><a href="{% url ''%}">Delete</a></li>          </ul>      </div>  </div>  <h2 id="title" class="title">{{obj.title}}</h2></div><div class="container">  <div class="action1">      <div class="icon" onclick="menuToggle1(event);">          <img src="{% static 'images/ore.svg'%}" class="svg">      </div>      <div class="menupost" id="menupost">          <ul>              <li><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:10px;"></i><a href="{% url ''%}">Update</a></li>              <li><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:10px;"></i><a href="{% url ''%}">Delete</a></li>          </ul>      </div>  </div>  <h2 id="title" class="title">{{obj.title}}</h2></div>
```

Comment: No worries, I didn't realize you had the more complicated sibling situation. Glad it helped.